# Can I securely allow users of my site to change their email address if they forgot their password and no longer have access to the old email address?

Tags: email, security, accounts

How do I securely allow users to change their emails if they lose access to the original email? Do I need 2 factor?

It's a social media site coded in nodejs where I have their username, password, and email address. Users sometimes want to change their emails because they lost their password to their old email address. However I use sending confirmation emails to their email as my way of authentication for actions like changing password. What can I do or is there no way but to just allow this be an insecure action.

I'm concerned that if someone, say a girlfriend or a roommate gets access to a computer that person is on and claims a lost email they can take over the account.

Comment: 2FA using google authenticator might help.

Answer (score 1):

Yes with a way to verify the users identity that does not include accessing or sending a link to their old email. I would setup either 2FA or use the good old 3 questions, but with questions there is a chance that other people could know the answers and could reset it, 2FA using GAuth seems the way to go as the person that owns the account will/should have access to that personal device and as you know those codes expire often and cannot be guessed by a significant.